# ADB wifi on Android 8.1 permanent

Tags: android, adb, wifi

```html
./adb devices
./adb tcpip 5555
./adb connect x.x.x.x
```

works for me in Android 8.1, but after reboot I have to do it again.

How can I make this permanent?

greetings

Comment: There is no way to make it permanent, but you can run a shell script on login to run the above code assuming you use a static ip using dhcp on your android device

Comment: MI use the device as  TV Box, android is build by the Board manufacture. To run a script on start up would not be a Problem, but how can I install adb on Android?